# Can not connect Github from my vps Ubuntu by ssh.

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh

How can i connect my vps Ubuntu to Github via SSH?
So i already add my public ssh key to the server by

```
ssh-copy-id
```

Now i can login my vps via ssh just fine.
but when i run 
    ssh git@github.com

i got

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

and my .ssh folder already have this 2 folder

```
authorized_keys  known_hosts
```

I also added my public key to my github account.
And ran this

```
git config --global user.name "myname"
git config --global user.email "myemail@domain.com"
```

i still got

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

So how can i fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Your .ssh folder should have the private key belonging to the public key you uploaded to github..

Comment: have you added the key to ssh using `ssh-add key_name`?

Comment: @kenney i need to add my local id_rsa to the server?

Comment: @gabe3886 what is key_name?

Comment: No, the id_rsa is private - you keep that secret, and give away the .pub. But it's not in the `~/.ssh` folder, as it should be. It will be auto-detected.

Comment: @user3403614 the key_name will be whatever the name of the key is you need to add to the authentication agent. see http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-add

Comment: @Kenney i made id_rsa.pub inside .ssh folder but still got the same error.

Comment: @gabe3886  i made id_rsa.pub inside .ssh folder and i ran ssh-add id_rsa.pub but still got the same error.

Comment: Have you worked through the guide at https://help.github.com/categories/ssh/ to create a new key on your VPS and logged tried doing t that way rather than copying keys from one place to another?  This has the added benefit of if (when?) your server gets hacked you can disable the key and limit the damage without affecting other machines using the key

Comment: @user3403614: you need the **private** key in `~/.ssh/` as I said before, which is the `id_dsa` file.

Comment: @Kenney yes after i upload secret it worked but is it a bit risky?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to create a keypair on server:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -N '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Then add the public part (`~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) to github using web interface (you don't have to remove the previous one you use from your computer).

And then you should be able to connect from your server using

```
ssh -vvv git@github.com verify
```

If not, post the log generated by the last command.